# Is there something like "goto last location" in emacs, which is CTRL + o in vim

Tags: org-mode

I would like to jump easily to the last location, I have been before, which is possible in vim.  Is there something analog to that in emacs?

Comment: What does `C-o` do in `vim` exactly? Do not assume that we know what that does. Please edit your question with additional information.

Comment: What @NickD said. Define "last location". When you move forward one character, do you want the "last location" to be `(1- point)`? Not at all clear what you're requesting.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/244291 (I guess you can tweak the behavior by adding appropriate hook functions for 'pushing global marks'). However, personally I am just using [evil-mode](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil), to get the best of both worlds .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-u C-SPC` will

> Move point to where the mark was, and restore the mark from the ring
> of former marks.

which usually does the trick within a buffer. For movement that takes into account all buffers, I usually rely on `C-x C-SPC`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe exchange-point-and-mark? C-x C-x?

Answer (score 1):

I used vim for years so I do understand your question.

Provided you have better-jump installed and better-jump-mode on, you can bind better-jump-forward and better-jump-backward to C-i and C-o to get essentially the same functionality.